# display math fraction using mathjax

Tags: math

I'm using mathjax in ckeditor and i want to print the fraction.So,what command i have to write to print the fraction mentioned in the link below?
(here is the image : tinypic.com/r/23k465g/9

Here is what i'm trying:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>

<title> mathsjax</title>
</head>
<body>
$$7\(frac\({4}{3}\)\)$$
</body>
</html>
```

But it isn't working.
So , please suggest me a solution

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 7):

```
$$7\frac{4}{3}$$
```

or in a text line

```
$7\dfrac{4}{3}$
```

Note that `\(...\)` defines a text line math environment, i.e., in LaTeX is equivalent to `$...$`.

Comment: Here goes a random note: I was typesetting math expressions in "options in a Quiz" through oTree. There, I needed to escape the \ character in `\frac{1}{2}` when introducing fractions to the options for a quiz.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HI!</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <mn>20</mn>
  <mfrac>
    <mn>47</mn>
    <mn>100</mn>
  </mfrac>
</math>
</body>
</html>
```